# JAVA: How can I make this work without using thread?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, try-catch

```
public class CarGame extends JFrame {
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private JLabel label;
        private int x, y;
        public MyThread(String fname, int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fname));
            label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
            add(label);
        }
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
                x += 10 * Math.random();
                label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public CarGame() {
        setTitle("Car Race");
        setSize(600, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        (new MyThread("car1.gif", 100, 0)).start();
        (new MyThread("car2.gif", 100, 50)).start();
        (new MyThread("car3.gif", 100, 100)).start();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarGame t = new CarGame();
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm a university student and I got a question while studying JAVA.
I want to make this Car Game works without using any thread.
Please help me!
Thank you :)

Comment: One problem is that the swing gui runs in it's own thread. You can't escape that.

Comment: Also the main thread is always there, that's going to be impossible to get rid of.

Comment: without threads, no execution is possible.

Comment: You might want to just use a `List` or array to keep the `JLabels` and others together, then loop them all in a single method and use the single main thread for it. You don't need a thread per image for it.

Comment: What is the point of this question??? What does or doesn't work? Are you trying to achieve animation? If so then you need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object for every car which holds its state. Put all cars in a list and iterate over it 200 times:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CarGame extends JFrame {
    
    class Car {
        private JLabel label;
        private int x, y;
        public Car(String fname, int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fname));
            label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
            add(label);
        }
        
        public void move()
        {
            x += 10 * Math.random();
            label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
            repaint();          
        }
    }
    
    public CarGame() {
        setTitle("Car Race");
        setSize(600, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        List<Car> cars=Arrays.asList(new Car("car1.gif", 100, 0),new Car("car2.gif", 100, 50),new Car("car3.gif", 100, 100));
        setVisible(true);
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            cars.forEach(car->car.move());
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarGame t = new CarGame();
    }
}
```

You will always have one thread.

Remark: using Thread.sleep() for this purpose is not such a good idea as it will block the thread from doing other work. Better would be to use a timer which is triggered every 100ms and calls the `cars.foreach(…)`. Off course this would result in a second thread. The timer can be canceled once the first (or last) car reaches the finish. (thanks to @JoopEggen for the valid comment)

For completeness (and because it was fun to do): a version without threads but with :

- javax.swing.Timer which stops after all cars finished.
- counts the final position of each car
- displays a text for those like who don't have a car gif.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    
    public class CarGame extends JFrame {
        int width = 600;
    
        int position=1;
        
        class Car {
            private JLabel label;
            private int x, y;
    
            public Car(String fname, int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                label = new JLabel(fname+">");
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fname+".gif"));
                label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
                add(label);
            }
    
            public boolean move() {
                if (!finished()) {
                    x += 10 * Math.random();
                    label.setBounds(x, y, 100, 100);
                    if(finished())
                        label.setText(label.getText()+"["+(position++)+"]");
                }
                return finished();
            }
    
            public boolean finished() {
                return x > width;
            }
        }
    
        public CarGame() {
            setTitle("Car Race");
            setSize(width+100, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setLayout(null);
            List<Car> cars = Arrays.asList(new Car("car1", 100, 0), new Car("car2", 100, 50),
                    new Car("car3", 100, 100));
            setVisible(true);
            Timer timer=new Timer(100,null);
            timer.addActionListener(e-> {
                    // count the number of non-finished cars
                    if(cars.stream().map(car -> car.move()).filter(b->!b).count()==0)
                        timer.stop();
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new CarGame();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of sleep(100) a Timer (thread) scheduled every 100 ms would be nice too.

Comment: @JoopEggen but than again you would use multiple threads (in the background but still)

Comment: That's why you got my upvote, but between sleeping and a timer the choice seems clear. A sleep also assumes the system to continue, not to freeze. Mentioning a timer would have been nice.

Comment: While this may work with it goes against standard Swing practice, which is that all Swing components or the state of the components must be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Also there is no need to invoke repaint() on each individual component when it is moved. Swing is smart enough to invoke revalidate() and repaint() when a property of a component is changed, or you could just invoke repaint on the entire panel after each component has been moved. So using a Swing Timer is the proper solution.